# Unable to set just year with Linux date command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, rhel

For some reason I fail to update year only using date command

```
date
Tue Mar  4 20:15:42 IST 2014

date '+%Y' -s '2013'

date
Tue Mar  4 20:13:01 IST 2014
```

I tried it on both RedHat and Ubuntu...

NTP is not running...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Linux administration: possibly try unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

Apparently to change the date you have to use the complete setting syntax.

```
date --set="YYYYmmdd HH:MM"
```

Here is a way to achieve your demand :

```
date --set="$(date +'2013%m%d %H:%M')"
```

This way you maintain month, day, hour and minute and change year.