# How to change the date dynamically using a command in linux

Tags: python, linux, datetime

I am writing a python code to change the date in linux system to today-1 (dynamically).  I tried various combinations but, yet I am not able to succeed.  I searched and I found a close proximity to my scenario [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168639/unable-to-set-just-year-with-linux-date-command) .

I am able to change the date if I execute the command with static value say:

```
date --set="$(date +'2013%m%d %H:%M')"
```

However, I don't want to specify hardcoded value for year i.e., 2013. Instead i want to specify something like `"%y-1"` i.e.,

```
date --set="$(date +'%y-1%m%d %H:%M')"
```

If I run the above command I get the following error

```
[root@ramesh ~]$ date --set="$(date +'%y-1%m%d %H:%M')"
date: invalid date `14-11016 13:05'
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081310/python-module-to-change-system-date-and-time

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answer.  I did not try your approach though, reason being it has to be once again dealt with formatting issues when working with arithmetic operations incase if you want to.

So, I figured out a much simpler and generalized approach

Fetch the previous_year value with this command

`date --date='1 years ago'`

This gives the previous year date.  Now this can be used in the python program to update the system in the following way

`"date --set=$(date +'%%y%%m%s %%H:%%M') % previous_year"`

This method has few advantages like

1. I can apply this method for day and month as well like `"1 days ago", "1 month ago"` along with `+%d, +%m, +%y` values.

   e.g., `date --date='1 years ago' +%y`
2. I don't have to worry about the date and month arithmetic calculation logics

Answer (score 0):

`date` will interpret the `%y-1` literally has you showed. What you need is to retrieve the current year, subtract 1 and use this value as the new year.
To get the `current_year - 1` you can do:

```
previous_year=$((`date +'%y'`-1))
echo $previous_year 
>>> 13
```

Now you just need to use this variable to set the new date.